# matplotlib contour plots; 'module' object has no attribute 'nextafter'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to reproduce the problem from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196704/matplotlib-contour-plot-with-slider-widget), I've found I can't plot even a simplest contour plot.

Here is a simplified version of a (hopefelly) relevant example from the [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
#Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)   
#Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * np.exp(X-Y)  #(Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

which gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./contour.py", line 19, in <module>
    CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2188, in contour
    ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7316, in contour
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1106, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 720, in __init__
    self._process_colors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 954, in _process_colors
    self.set_clim(self.vmin, self.vmax)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 248, in set_clim
    self.changed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 841, in changed
    self.to_rgba(self.cvalues, alpha=self.alpha)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 214, in to_rgba
    x = self.cmap(x, alpha=alpha, bytes=bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 520, in __call__
    cbook._putmask(xa, xa==1.0, np.nextafter(xa.dtype.type(1),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nextafter'
```

The errors do not depend on whether I stick to the original 'difference of Gaussians' or try plotting just an exponential, as in the code snipped above.

Am I missing something trivial?

In case it's relevant, I'm using `matplotlib 1.1.0` on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: To help narrow it down, the code works for me on Ubuntu `11.10` with matplotlib `1.0.1`.

Comment: I would consider changing the title of your question. It had nothing to do with contour plots. It's a good question to ask, and someone else might have the same issue. Something like "Error running matplotlib: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nextafter'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are not doing anything wrong. You need to upgrade Numpy. I had the same issue, and following an update to Numpy 1.6.1, things worked smoothly.

With Lucid Lynx (Ubuntu 10.04), you have access to [numpy 1.3.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-numpy). The missing `nextafter` function is only available following [numpy 1.4](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html#npy_nextafter) (Thanks to [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)).

Comment: I've just checked, and the nextafter function is missing from numpy 1.3.0 and present in numpy 1.4.1 and beyond, so I bet the numpy version is 1.3.0.

Comment: hey, there's rep enough for everyone. :-)